# HTML5 and MySQL date format

Tags: mysql, html

I am unable to insert HTML5 default date  format(mm/dd/yyyy) in mysql(YYYY-mm-dd).Please help is there any way to insert the html5 date into mysql. Or is it possible to change the html5/mysql date format?

```
<?php
  $name=$_POST['name'];
  $email=$_POST['email'];
  $password=$_POST['password'];
  $gender=$_POST['gender'];
  $bday=$_POST['bday'];
  include('connect.php');
  $y=mysql_query("insert into users values('$name','$email','$password','$gender','$bday')");
?>
```

Comment: What server-side language are you using to do this? Do you have any code to show? As this question stands, it's not a good format for Stack Overflow. Please read the **[FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)** for more details.

Comment: Mysql has a fuction to format dates. [DATE_FORMAT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format

Comment: @brbcodin I am using php

Comment: Great, now let's see the php you are using.

Comment: yes. please see my code 

<?php

$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$gender=$_POST['gender'];
$bday=$_POST['bday'];
include('connect.php');
$y=mysql_query("insert into users values('$name','$email','$password','$gender','$date')");

 ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change MySQL date format in your query you can use:

...since we can see your code

**EDIT:**

```
 mysql_query("insert into users values('$name','$email','$password','$gender',".date('Ymd',$bday))
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: This function expects a MySQL date format already if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

$date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date));

?>
```